# Automatically recall a javascript function in a controller in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, function, codeigniter, google-maps

I have this code and I would add in a function of a controller in codeigniter:

```
function myFunction() {
    var address = 'my address';
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( {'address': address}, function(results,status) {

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {
            alert('Latitude: ' + results[0].geometry.location.lat() + 'Longitude: ' + results[0].geometry.location.lng());
        }
        else 
        {
            alert("Error: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

My goal is to enter the latitude and longitude in the database, so I decided to enter the code at the beginning of the function in my controller with the code `echo`, but does not work.

(I tried, always at the beginning of the function of my controller, an `echo` composed, and it works: `echo '<script>alert(myVar)</script>';` )

Comment: You should make sure your lat and long is there by logging them before you insert it into the databse. So before you do echo, check your values. Also make sure in the database, the you are getting the correct columns for inserting your data.

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks for the reply.
Then I wanted to say that my problem is not to enter the latitude and longitude in the respective column or have values that returns the function, because the same function I inserted into a html page and it works perfectly!

The only problem is that if I try to use JavaScript in a controller gives me problems and does not start any function.
Thank You.

Comment: Ah, sorry ... another problem would be how to call a function.
I have tried in many ways but none of these works, only 'window.onload' but does not do for me.